# generated pdf open with new tab using symonfy 1.4

Tags: symfony-1.4, tcpdf

I am using symfony 1.4. I have application lists. From there I generated a pdf action. After generate I want to open pdf with new tab or windows. How could I do that.

Comment: Do you mean you want to send the file directly to the browser?

Comment: yes but I want to open it with new browser tab.

Comment: If you have a working action which creates and sends the pdf to the browser you just need to add a `target` argument to the link which points to the pdf. Adding `target="new"` to the `<a>` element will open it in a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show generated PDF in new window/tab after clicking a link, just try:

```
<a href="<?php echo url_for('@your_action_route') ?>" target="_blank">PDF</a>
```

or

```
<?php echo link_to('PDF','@your_action_route',array('target' => '_blank')) ?>
```

---

If you want to echo a link from action:

```
sfApplicationConfiguration::getActive()->loadHelpers(array('Url'));
```

and then use `link_to` or `url_for` as needed (examples above).

---

If you want to serve a PDF through action, but not as a download:

Make a new routing

```
pdf:
  url: /pdf/:filename.pdf/*
  param: { module: mymodule, action: show }
```

And then create this action in mymodule/actions/actions.class.php :

```
  public function executeServepdf(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->setLayout(false);
    sfConfig::set('sf_web_debug', false);

    $pdf = sfConfig::get('sf_web_dir').
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.
            'uploads'.
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.
            $request->getParameter('filename').'.pdf';

    $this->forward404Unless(file_exists($pdf));

    $this->getResponse()->clearHttpHeaders();
    $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Pragma: public', true);
    $this->getResponse()->setContentType('application/pdf');
    $this->getResponse()->sendHttpHeaders();
    $this->getResponse()->setContent(readfile($pdf));

    return sfView::NONE;
  }
```

Now, if you put your PDF in web/uploads/your_file.pdf directory 
and enter URL like: `http://yoursite/pdf/your_file.pdf`
you will get your PDF displaying directly in browser window.

To open it as a new window/tab use `target="_blank"` attribute for `<a>` element as pointed in first example.

Also, mayby this site will be helpful: http://www.symfony-zone.com/wordpress/2009/08/03/serving-pdf-files-through-symfony-controllers/ I used example from it.

Comment: How could I use from execute Action page

Comment: @Md.ModasserHossain I've edited answer, hope one of those examples helps